# rm - command not found

Tags: macos, bash

I recently wanted to use the `rm` command in Terminal on my Mac. To my surprise, it just reponds with:

```
-bash: rm: command not found
```

I can use `mv`, `cp`, `cd`, `ls` etc. However `rm` somehow doesn't work. I can't use `/bin/rm` either.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Does the file `/bin/rm` acually *exist*?

Comment: You didn't happen to have run `sudo rm rm` from the `/bin` folder by any chance? ;)

Comment: I dont know.. How do i check.. and how do i repair it :S

Comment: your system could be compromised...

Comment: I had a similar problem, trying to delete a "file in use". Initially, it recognised the command, giving a warning and asking for password. However, the file wasn't deleted, but the rm command did not exist anymore. This file has strange behaviour, as it changes name when trying to delete with secure empty trash.

Comment: Check the Trash for the /bin/rm file?

Comment: You can also try the following to see if its anywhere on the machine: `sudo find / -name rm`. It will start looking for the `rm` command in `/`. If you find it, then verify its location/path and check permissions on it. If not, then you should look for ways to restore it.

Answer (score 3):

Can you give us the output of the following commands:

```
stat /bin/rm
```

and

```
echo $PATH
```

Does the problem persists when you open a new terminal?

Did you do anything particular before trying to use the rm command?

---

**Update:** The output of your first command confirms that your command rm is missing. Why, I have no idea. Maybe, by error, while being sudo-ed, you did something like `/bin/rm /bin/rm`.
To fix it, can you try to copy the executable file command from an other mac?

Comment: stat: /bin/rm: stat: No such file or directory
and

Comment: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: And no i've tried to restart/ and repair with disc utility and so on.. Just doesnt work.. Maybe my bashcr file is messed up. But i dont know how to fix it :S

Comment: @s0mmer: Your "bashcr" is in no way related to missing system commands. Read the output of the 'stat' command again.

Comment: If you're taking TimeMachine backups of your system, use that to travel back in time on the /bin directory and restore the `rm` command from the TM backup.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar occurrence, however, mine was

```
sudo: rm: command not found
```

This was caused by incorrectly altering the path in ~/.bash_profile